# How to auto-refresh website and update me when its page source changed?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm looking forward to knowing when there is a new "free room" available on a booking website.

I think I can make a refresh script, but how can I add an "if" condition over a variable in the page source to update me when it changed? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'd look into something using websockets, they'd be able to push out notifications to clients.

Comment: Can you provide me more specific advice? I don't know much about websockets.

Comment: I'd start here: http://socket.io/ Learn how to build a basic NodeJS server and then learn the Socket API, it can be a little brain bending, but it's worth it.

Comment: I was more looking for a solution like: create this script on the desktop, write this code and keep it running. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try polling for variable change repeatedly using `setInterval`, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

EDIT:
If you want to download the whole page periodically you can do something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    //this function is called repeatedly
    $.ajax("/path/to/your/page")
     .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         // check for changes and reload the page
      });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But how can I specify that the variable is from that website's Page Source? I don't own the server.

Comment: Well, you could request the new version of page via AJAX, but that is a weird solution.

Comment: Nice idea. Can you help me with downloading a Page Source with Chrome?

Comment: I'm thinking of downloading the page every 1 second and then check for the variable, if it is changed, pop up an alert.

Comment: If you use jQuery, here is the documentation about its ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Remember that if you don't own the domain AJAX calls to it may be disallowed due to the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping me. I managed to deliver what I wanted using this easy PHP script that downloads and searches for a string on the page's source:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000000; ++$i) {
    $ch = curl_init("www.webpage.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $text = curl_exec($ch);

    $test = strpos($text, "Sorry, no rooms available.");

    if ($test)
    {
        echo "No rooms left.";  
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ROOM AVAILABLE.\n';
        $exec = "terminal-notifier -message \"Room Available\"";
        shell_exec($exec);        
    }
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

It uses `terminal-notifier` to send you a notification on OS X.

https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier

To run it, open Terminal: `:php script.php`